# 4 Images in HTML, need help to show the small picture when hovered in the large picture

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have 3 Images in line in HTML, and a large one below, and the 1 large one below it is the same image as one of the top 3. No thumbnails or anything being used. All I want done is when I Hover over the first small image it should show and change the bottom image, and if I hover away it changes back to its original,  and same with the 2 other photos when I hover the large pic at the bottom should should it.
Organized like(in html)

Pic1 pic2 pic3

Pic4(larger)

```
  <img src="guitars.jpg" width="80" height="60" alt="Guitars"> 
  <img src="control.jpg" width="80" height="60" alt="Control Room" onmouseover=""> 
  <img src="singing.jpg" width="80" height="60" alt="Singing Room" onmouseover=""> 
  <br> 
  <img src="guitars.jpg" width="400" height="300">
```

Comment: This isn't too complex of a task, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please add some code samples.

Comment: I'm new at this, iv tried some functions they did not work, just trying to wrap what concept i should use to get it done.

Comment: <img src="guitars.jpg" width="80" height="60" alt="Guitars"> 
      <img src="control.jpg" width="80" height="60" alt="Control Room" onmouseover=""> 
      <img src="singing.jpg" width="80" height="60" alt="Singing Room" onmouseover=""> 
      <br> 
      <img src="guitars.jpg" width="400" height="300"> 
   </body> 
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to give you an example with only two elements (*with only a single one having the event functionality*), in which then you can expand to 3 images. The basic idea is to change the `src` of the large image to the `this.src` of the image when hovered (in JS it's the `onmouseover` event). Then on `onmouseout` set the `src` back to it's normal image. If the original image is just the first small image simply set it to that `<img>` element. Otherwise keep track of it.

In the following example `#main` is the large image, `#apple` is the first small image and `#banana` the second small image.

```
// This gets the original src of the main (large image)
// That way when it's changed we can refer to this variable to revert it
var original = document.getElementById("main").src;

// On mouseover the "banana" image, that the src of the main image to src of the banana
document.getElementById("banana").onmouseover = function(){
    document.getElementById("main").src = this.src;
}

// On mouseout of "banana" we change the main image back to it's original image
document.getElementById("banana").onmouseout = function(){
    document.getElementById("main").src = original;
}
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jt8xduqp/)

Comment: Thanks alot! Makes sense!

Comment: @Wieczorek can you explain why I need var original = document.getElementById("main").src; in the beginning?  Thanks

Comment: @Wieczorek if you could explain each line please, that would be great

Comment: @Sid Sure, I've added comments explaining what each line does. Just note that if you know what the original image is for the large image. Say it's `#apple`. Then you can say `... = document.getElementById("apple").src;` rather than `... = original;` and omit `original` all together.

Comment: @Wieczorek I tried it but nothing works sadly, here is my code

document.getElementById("control").onmouseover = function(){
 document.getElementById("main").src = this.src;
}

document.getElementById("control").onmouseout = function(){
 document.getElementById("main").src = original;
}
         
  document.getElementById("singing").onmouseover = function(){
 document.getElementById("main").src = this.src;
}

document.getElementById("singing").onmouseout = function(){
 document.getElementById("main").src = original;
}

Comment: @Sid It doesn't seem like you define `original`.

Comment: @Sid Here is example with that fix, note that you need to click the element and "view source" to see the change in the `src` attribute.

Comment: Sorry didint add top, i did add it, but still no luck

var original = document.getElementById("main").src;
document.getElementById("control").onmouseover = function(){
 document.getElementById("main").src = this.src;
}

document.getElementById("control").onmouseout = function(){
 document.getElementById("main").src = original;
}
         
  document.getElementById("singing").onmouseover = function(){
 document.getElementById("main").src = this.src;
}

document.getElementById("singing").onmouseout = function(){
 document.getElementById("main").src = original;
}

Comment: @Wieczorek i added the var aswell which i had but still no luck

Comment: @Wieczorek
<img id="guitar" src="guitars.jpg" width="80" height="60" alt="Guitars">
      <img id="control" src="controls.jpg" width="80" height="60" alt="Control Room" onmouseover="">
      <img id="singing" src="singings.jpg" width="80" height="60" alt="Singing Room" onmouseover="">
      <br>
      <img id="main" src="guitars.jpg" width="400" height="300">

Comment: @Sid Sorry didn't notice I didn't link, [here is the example](http://jsfiddle.net/7cL5u4wj/).

Comment: @Wieczorek, thanks I will check it out. But why did we add console.log only on the first one? What's the point of it

Comment: @Sid You can remove that, I was just debugging when I added that to make sure `this.src` gave the right value. And I forgot to take it out.

Comment: @Wieczorek I tried it but my images dont move or anything, should my onmouseover=""(Should it be like that with the quotes? or make a function name? thanks for all your help

Comment: @Sid Remove the `onmouseover=""`, it's possible that overwrites your functions for `onmouseover` in JavaScript. Basically that says do nothing `onmouseover`.

Comment: @Wieczorek sadly nothing :( can I send you all my code I have somehow? It's just a basic site with 3 pics at the bottom

Comment: @Wieczorek I figured a way out
function switchImage() {
document.gui.src="control.jpg";
}
function restoreImage() {
document.gui.src="guitars.jpg";
}

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to implement onclick or onmouseover event on the small images, and update the src value of the big image.

See this for reference: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb

---

If you want to easily add more images in the future, then you might want a slider with custom pager.

If you are comfortable with jQuery, I recommend this plugin because it is fairly easy to use:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/
(Check out the carousel pager demo)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! But we are just supposed to use Javascript to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try using `css` `:hover` , `:nth-of-type()` , `:not()` , general siblings selector

```css
img:not(.lg) {
  width:50px;
  height: 50px;
}

img.lg {
  width:160px;
  height:160px;
  background-image:url(http://placehold.it/160/ff0000/ffffff);
}

img:nth-of-type(1) {
   background-image:url(http://placehold.it/50/ff0000/ffffff);
}

img:nth-of-type(2) {
   background-image:url(http://placehold.it/50/00ff00/ffffff);
}

img:nth-of-type(3) {
   background-image:url(http://placehold.it/50/0000ff/ffffff);
}

img:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ .lg {
  background-image:url(http://placehold.it/160/ff0000/ffffff);
}

img:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ .lg {
  background-image:url(http://placehold.it/160/00ff00/ffffff);
}
img:nth-of-type(3):hover ~ .lg {
  background-image:url(http://placehold.it/160/0000ff/ffffff);
}
```

```html
<img /> <img /> <img /> <br />
<img class="lg" />
```